# What happen if I uncheck all PPAs from 'Software & Updates'

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager, ppa

What happen if I uncheck all items in 'Other Software' from 'Software & Updates'?

No longer have new updates for packages??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By disabling your PPAs, you will no longer be able to get updates through those PPAs.  For example, if you were using the NGINX Stable PPAs on your system, and I issue an update to update a security fix and it ONLY exists in that PPA (since those versions are newer than Ubuntu), you would not get those updates.

ONLY disable all your PPAs and items in "Other Software" if you know what you're doing, and you really don't want the software or updates available in those repository sources.

Answer (score 1):

you'll not get update notifications from those PPAs.